# Is there any user limit for distributing apps in playstore private channel?

Tags: android

I am developing an android app for thousands of users in private channel. Is there any restriction for the user limit in private channel, Or is there anything that I should be concerned about like

- Price
- Validity
- Permissions

Since I don’t have a developer account, I cant check it for myself. please help

Please excuse me if the question is already there.I am totally a newbie in application development :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the policy for Google Play Store. Reading this will give you an idea of guidelines and limitations - [Google Play Developer Policy](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html)

Things you can learn about from the link above are as follows:

- Content Policies
- Network Usage and Terms
- Spam and Placement in the Store
- App Promotion
- Paid and Free Apps
- Subscriptions and Cancellations

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, But this seems like the developer policy, I was wondering if there is any more details about private channel apart from this https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992?hl=en

Comment: private channel is basically the same thing which allows you to distribute apps internally within the organization. I think more or less the same rules apply there as in the public facing play store.

Comment: Thank you, I will proceed with this as the note. Once again thank you for the quick reply :)